# Is there a way to add methods to GregorianCalendar in Java?

Tags: java, comparison, operators, operator-overloading, gregorian-calendar

I'd like to make a method called "isBetween" returning a boolean, seeing if a GregorianCalendar date falls between two others. Alternatively, I'd like to just define operators of < and > for the class. I'm pretty new to Java, so I'm not sure....can I even do either of those? If so, how?

Comment: Answer advising use of Joda time in 3,2,1

Comment: Use Joda time: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/ (sorry i'm late!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java does not support monkeypatching or operator overloading, but feel free to subclass `GregorianCalendar` and add whatever methods you need.

But then, do you really need a new method to do `cal.after(startCal) && cal.before(endCal)` ?

Comment: Clearly, I missed the existence of before and after. I saw them about a minute before seeing your answer. Thanks

Comment: @timdiggerm: the Calendar API is big and disorganized, so it's easy to overlook things, especially methods in the abstract superclass...

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't add method to pre-existing classes and you can't do operator overloading either in Java.

As an alternative, you could provide a static utility method in your own class for example.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise *against* extending the class - you're not adding any behaviour which is specific to instances of a particular class, you're expressing logic which is applicable for any `GregorianCalendar` (or possibly any calendar at all).

As Joachim says, a static method in a utility class is the way to go - and if Java ever gains extension methods as per C# (I know they were suggested for Java 7, but I *think* they're out at the moment) you can modify them at that point.

Oh, and use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to extend it:

```
class MyGregorianCalendar extends GregorianCalendar
```